# How can I speedup data transfer from memory to CPU?

Tags: c++, performance, openmp, bit-manipulation, dma

I am trying to speedup a popcount function. Here is the code:

```
extern ll LUT16[];
typedef long long ll;
typedef unsigned char* pUChar;
ll LUT16Word32Monobit(pUChar buf, int size) {
    assert(buf != NULL);
    assert(size > 0);
    assert(size % sizeof(unsigned) == 0);
    int n = size / sizeof(unsigned);
    unsigned* p = (unsigned*)buf;
    ll numberOfOneBits = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        unsigned int val1 = p[i];
        numberOfOneBits += LUT16[val1 >> 16] + LUT16[val1 & 0xFFFF];
    }
    return numberOfOneBits;
}
```

Here are a few details:

- buf contains 1 GB of data
- LUT16[i] contains the number of one bits in the binary representation of i, for all 0 <= i < 2^16

I tried to use openMP for speeding things up, but it doesn't work. I must add that I am using MS Visual Studio 2010 and that I have enabled the openMP directives. I believe that one of the reasons openMP doesn't speedup things up is due to memory access time. Is there any way I could make use of DMA(direct memory access)?

Also, I should warn you that my openMP skills are missing; that being said here is the openMP part(kind of the same code as above):

```
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,CHUNKSIZE)
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    unsigned int val1 = p[i];
    numberOfOneBits += LUT16[val1 >> 16] + LUT16[val1 & 0xFFFF];
}
```

CHUNKSIZE is set to 64. If I set it lower, the results are worse than in the serial version, if I set it higher, it doesn't do any good.

Also, I don't want to use the popcount instruction that processors provide, neither the SSE instructions.

Comment: DMA is essentially for copying memory to/from peripherals...

Comment: To get the right result with OpenMP you need to do a reduction.  Also I don't think you want to use `schedule(dynamic)`.  Try `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:numberOfOneBits)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `LUT16` array is 512kB (assuming a `long long` is 64-bit), which will completely destroy your L1/L2 cache performance for arbitrary/random data (L1 is typically 32kB, L2 is typically 256kB).

Firstly, you don't need `long long` for this.  Secondly, try `LUT8` instead.  Thirdly, just use the builtin [`__popcnt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) intrinsic.

Comment: Hello! I have downgraded the type from long long to unsigned char and it works faster now. But after trying with a LUT8, it worked slower. Probably because more instructions are executed if we use LUT8. So LUT16 is fine. I have now also tried the __popcnt intrinsic. Apparently, my machine doesn;t support(?!) this intrinsic.

Comment: @MciprianM: Ok, I'm surprised that LUT8 was slower.  There are indeed more operations, but the entire array should fit in L1 cache, and therefore should incur no cache misses at all.  Oh well...

Comment: Have you tried other methods? http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel